# Dumping CSV files to MySQL database using embedded query in python script

Tags: python, mysql, csv, python-2.7

I have a SQL query which opens up a csv file and dumps it in a table of a database. I am trying to dump multiple files at once using a python script to iterate among the files. I tried embedding the same SQL query inside the script, but it throws out an error.

This is the script I have.

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='password',
    db='some_db')


cursor = connection.cursor()

query = """ LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:\\example.csv' INTO TABLE new_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' Lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES """

cursor.execute(query)

conenction.commit()
cursor.close()
```

And for some reason the python script looks up example.csv at a different location

This is the error that is thrown out :

```
raise errorclass, errorvalue
InternalError: (29, "File 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Application Data\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\data\\example.csv' not found (Errcode: 2)")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am also searching on stackoverflow for help to dump the scv files into differnt tables of a database. Any ideas on  that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need the `load data local` syntax to make sure the data is being read relative to the client and not the server. Change

```
query = """ LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:\\example.csv' INTO TABLE new_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' Lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES """
```

to

```
query = """ LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:\\example.csv' INTO TABLE new_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' Lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES """
```

Comment: For some reason there is an error when I give your answer a thumbs up.

Comment: @KumaranSenapathy Glad it worked. BTW, you could just accept the answer instead of up-voting.

Answer (score 0):

Watch your spelling! conenction.commit() should be connection.commit()